# Error Adding MvvmCross NuGet package to PCL in VS2013

Tags: mvvmcross, visual-studio-2013

When I try to install MvvmCross on my PCL, I get the error message below.  I am running Visual Studio 2013 and the Xamarin Frameworks are installed for the PCLs.

I'm using Profile78, which targets .net framework 4.5, windows store apps (windows 8) and higher, Windows Phone 8, Xamarin.Android, and Xamarin.iOS.

Is there a better profile for me to use?

Could not install package 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.13'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+wp80+win+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This area is changing with many new releases from many different places. I don't believe there are any definitive answers here today. There's a walkthrough using the latest platforms on http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/quick-run-through-using-pcls-in.html

That walkthrough uses:

- Xamarin - iOS 1.8 & Android 4.10
- Nuget - 2.7.2
- MvvmCross - 3.0.14-beta3
- Visual Studio 2012
- portable profile 158

Other setups may also work - I don't know if anyone knows which is "better" - but it would be interesting to hear opinions!

Comment: In order to get Profile 158 working, do I need to first install WP8 sdk and must run on Windows 8 instead of Windows 7 OS?

Comment: Trying to open the Sample - Twitter Search solution, VS2013 fails to open TwitterSearch.Core telling me that it's incompatible? The ProjectTypeGuids seem to be C# + PCL. How can it be loaded in VS2013? (having installed Win 8.1)